# How to get img src with JSDOM (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mean-stack, jsdom

I need to find the `src` of the `img` tag in my string:

```
const dom = new JSDOM('<img src="godaddy.com">',
                      { includeNodeLocations: true });
console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("img"));
```

But the console output is:

```
HTMLImageElement {}
```

How can I get the value of the `src` attribute?

Comment: Try `dom.window.document.querySelector("img").getAttribute('src')`

Comment: dom.window.document.querySelector("img").attr('src'); ??

Comment: What if i have 2 image tags <img src="www.123.com"><img src="www.325.com">............?

Comment: Thanks guys it worked but need solution for 2 img tags

Comment: Use `querySelectorAll()` to get the array of elements and then loop through them and get the values.

Comment: Thank you very much.Can you please provide me docs link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've not used the jsdom myself, but assuming it pretty much has same api's as browser dom. You could be able to use this:

```
const dom = new JSDOM('<img src="godaddy.com">', { includeNodeLocations: true });
console.log(dom.window.document.querySelector("img").getAttribute('src');
```

If you have multiple images then you can use `querySelectorAll()` which returns a `NodeList` object representing the set of matched elements. You can then loop through this list and get the `src` values.

More about [querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

Comment: `querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` not an array.

Comment: It returns an HTML object with getter/setter functions. Use `.getAttribute('src')` to grab your source attribute!